# How can I check whether CUDA device peer access is enabled (rather than supported)?

Tags: multi-gpu, cuda-driver

If you have a pair of devices for which `cuDeviceCanAccessPeer()` is true, and you try
If you try to disable peer access `cuCtxDisablePeerAccess()` - you may get a failure, `CUDA_ERROR_PEER_ACCESS_NOT_ENABLED`. So, there's *ability* to access, and there's *enablement* of access. How does one check the state of enablement of access? That is, without disabling access?